# ReferenceError: Sys is not defined ReferenceError: WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions is not definded

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows

We have set up a new domain on my dedicated server where my old domains are working perfectly.

My site is built in asp.net.

On the new domain I have a copy of the code that is running on the old one. Both sites are on the same dedicated server. When I try to execute the code on the new site, I get the following error message:

> ReferenceError: Sys is not defined
>
> ReferenceEror: WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions is not definded

Can you please help me to resolve this issue?

Comment: may be ScriptManager was not added on the page

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/75322/sys-is-undefined

Answer (score 0):

There are some stuff you can check:

1. set the time on the server right [may it accurate]
2. try to install ajax on the server [if not already installed]
3. also this can be caused because of compression module. Try to add webresource.axd to the exclusion list for compression
4. Mostly this is caused by a corrupted webresource.axd on the client side. So please close your browser and delete your temporary internet files. Make sure the file stated above is cleaned from local hard disk. After that it shoudl work as normal.

Comment: Hi,
i have checked time and Ajax installation and both are correct.
its same server where my old application is working perfect so i really dont thing its a time or ajax issue.
for 3rd and 4th option can u please tell me how i can add webresource.axd file to excludion list?

Comment: i have simple remove that domain and create it again from scarp and my issue is resolved.

Comment: my projects are on shared hosting and i am compressing everything according this article http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7171434/iis-7-5-gzip-compression-at-shared-hosting/14509007#14509007. My problem was with compression, i excluded .axd files from compression and everything is ok now

Answer (score 0):

if using MVC - and in my case N2CMS, ensure the following code is in your route config or global asax...

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
```