# Enabling gzip compression on Azure Websites

Tags: asp.net, azure, compression, gzip, azure-web-app-service

I have an ASP.NET application running on an azure website using the standard tier. I have been trying to get gzip compression working on it. I've modified my `web.config` file and added the following under `system.webServer`

```
<urlCompression doStaticCompression="true" doDynamicCompression="true"/>
<httpCompression directory="%SystemDrive%\inetpub\temp\IIS Temporary Compressed Files">
    <dynamicTypes>
        <add mimeType="text/*" enabled="true"/>
        <add mimeType="message/*" enabled="true"/>
        <add mimeType="application/javascript" enabled="true"/>
        <add mimeType="application/x-javascript" enabled="true"/>
        <add mimeType="*/*" enabled="false"/>
    </dynamicTypes>
    <staticTypes>
        <add mimeType="text/*" enabled="true"/>
        <add mimeType="message/*" enabled="true"/>
        <add mimeType="application/javascript" enabled="true"/>
        <add mimeType="application/x-javascript" enabled="true"/>
        <add mimeType="*/*" enabled="false"/>
     </staticTypes>
</httpCompression>
```

This works when running locally with IIS express but does not work when deployed to azure. The response contains the following headers.

```
Accept-Ranges:bytes
Content-Length:5381
Content-Type:text/css
Date:Fri, 04 Sep 2015 20:44:01 GMT
ETag:"56386b2e88dad01:0"
Last-Modified:Wed, 19 Aug 2015 14:06:02 GMT
Server:Microsoft-IIS/8.0
X-Powered-By:ASP.NET
```

Comment: I think Gzip compression is enabled by default in Azure websites. so you shouldn't need any additional configs...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14722464/gzip-compression-in-windows-azure-websites

Comment: It's not working by default for me. Also not working when I try to add it to the web.config.

Answer (score 5):

You are missing the `<scheme>` element

```
<scheme name="gzip" dll="%Windir%\system32\inetsrv\gzip.dll" />
```

More info here:

https://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/httpcompression/scheme

```
<urlCompression doStaticCompression="true" doDynamicCompression="true"/>
<httpCompression directory="%SystemDrive%\inetpub\temp\IIS Temporary Compressed Files">
<scheme name="gzip" dll="%Windir%\system32\inetsrv\gzip.dll" />
    <dynamicTypes>
        <add mimeType="text/*" enabled="true"/>
        <add mimeType="message/*" enabled="true"/>
        <add mimeType="application/javascript" enabled="true"/>
        <add mimeType="application/x-javascript" enabled="true"/>
        <add mimeType="*/*" enabled="false"/>
    </dynamicTypes>
    <staticTypes>
        <add mimeType="text/*" enabled="true"/>
        <add mimeType="message/*" enabled="true"/>
        <add mimeType="application/javascript" enabled="true"/>
        <add mimeType="application/x-javascript" enabled="true"/>
        <add mimeType="*/*" enabled="false"/>
     </staticTypes>
</httpCompression>
```

Comment: I had this originally and ended up removing it while messing with the config. I just added it again but it does not work for me. There's still no gzipping going on.

Comment: how are you testing? I tested your original code and my code and both worked like it was supposed to. I had only to add the <scheme > in order to make it work.

Comment: I'm looking at the headers in the response from the website. The files are also the original size without compression. I should mention that this code **does** work when running locally with IIS Express, just not on azure.

Comment: @Jonathan Did you get a resolution for this...it is driving me nuts that it doesn't work.

Comment: @Darren Sorry, I had to go live with this and had to eat that small performance hit. Never got enough time to figure this out. It was driving me nuts too until I couldn't spend more time on it. I might revisit this in the future though. Let me know if you're able to solve this, I'd really like to know what's up with it.

Comment: @Jonathan Today I decided to move the site from 'Australia-SE' to 'East-Asia' region. Now it works.