# Why App Service Linux doesn't serve compressed(gzip) files for Angular application?

Tags: angular, linux, azure-web-app-service, compression, gzip

I have deployed my Angular app on Azure Web Service(gz files included) - App Service Linux, but responses returned aren't compressed so my app load is taking too long.
When I look at Network tab, I see that files which are served by server aren't compressed.
Also, when I check my xxx.azurewebsites.net website [here](https://www.giftofspeed.com/gzip-test/) it says that compression is not enabled. Is there a way to enable compressing for Azure App Service Linux?

Update: This app is running on Linux server.
I've found this useful link: https://azureossd.github.io/2022/07/13/Compression-on-App-Service-Linux/ but still don't know how to enable compression for an Angular app.

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35438406/1204153).

Comment: Thank you! I've added web.config file in my angular src folder, just like on this tutorial: https://medium.com/angular-in-depth/deploy-an-angular-application-to-iis-60a0897742e7

and added its content like in the answer you send me, but it's not being considered. Do you have idea why?