# Could not find Angular on page when enabling gzip on Azure IIS

Tags: angularjs, azure, gzip, http-compression

I just enabled gzip http compression on Azure IIS. I'm serving an AngularJS webpage. I suddenly got:

> Could not find Angular on page

on every single protractor e2e test I have in place

gzip compression is enabled, on my local environment everything works

Comment: Actually, gzip compression is enabled by default without any operation, you can refer to the answer of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34006236/azure-web-app-not-using-gzip-compression and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14722464/gzip-compression-in-windows-azure-websites. Could you double check your js libraries path, or could you please share your code with us?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, gzip compression is enabled by default without any operation, you can refer to the answer of [Azure Web App Not Using GZip Compression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34006236/azure-web-app-not-using-gzip-compression) and [gzip compression in Windows Azure Websites](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14722464/gzip-compression-in-windows-azure-websites).

According to your error message, it seems that there is a path issue of the Angular library file. Could you double check your js libraries path, or could you please share your code/project structure with us for further troubleshooting?