# azure app-service returning ERR_CONTENT_DECODING_FAILED

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-web-app-service, http-error

I have deployed my node application to azure but getting on all sides this error message: ERR_CONTENT_DECODING_FAILED

I have already tried several things like putting this into my web.config

```
<urlCompression doStaticCompression="true" doDynamicCompression="true" />
    <httpCompression>
      <dynamicTypes>
        <clear />
        <add enabled="true" mimeType="text/*"/>
        <add enabled="true" mimeType="message/*"/>
        <add enabled="true" mimeType="application/x-javascript"/>
        <add enabled="true" mimeType="application/javascript"/>
        <add enabled="true" mimeType="application/json"/>
        <add enabled="false" mimeType="*/*"/>
        <add enabled="true" mimeType="application/atom+xml"/>
        <add enabled="true" mimeType="application/atom+xml;charset=utf-8"/>
      </dynamicTypes>
      <staticTypes>
        <clear />
        <add enabled="true" mimeType="text/*"/>
        <add enabled="true" mimeType="message/*"/>
        <add enabled="true" mimeType="application/javascript"/>
        <add enabled="true" mimeType="application/atom+xml"/>
        <add enabled="true" mimeType="application/xaml+xml"/>
        <add enabled="true" mimeType="application/json"/>
        <add enabled="false" mimeType="*/*"/>
      </staticTypes>
    </httpCompression>
```

But nothing works.
Can someone help?

The website I deploy is this one:
https://github.com/aumanjoa/chronas-community

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took your website and deployed to Azure App Service. After setting the `CLOUDINARY_URL` value in **App settings** and connection string of `mongo`, I got the error as below.

[image]

Here is my web.config for reference.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<configuration>
     <system.webServer>
          <!-- Visit http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazure/archive/2013/11/14/introduction-to-websockets-on-windows-azure-web-sites.aspx for more information on WebSocket support -->
          <webSocket enabled="false" />
          <handlers>
               <!-- Indicates that the app.js file is a node.js site to be handled by the iisnode module -->
               <add name="iisnode" path="keystone.js" verb="*" modules="iisnode"/>
          </handlers>
          <rewrite>
               <rules>
                    <!-- Do not interfere with requests for node-inspector debugging -->
                    <rule name="NodeInspector" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">                    
                        <match url="^keystone.js\/debug[\/]?" />
                    </rule>

                    <!-- First we consider whether the incoming URL matches a physical file in the /public folder -->
                    <rule name="StaticContent">
                         <action type="Rewrite" url="public{REQUEST_URI}"/>
                    </rule>

                    <!-- All other URLs are mapped to the node.js site entry point -->
                    <rule name="DynamicContent">
                         <conditions>
                              <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="True"/>
                         </conditions>
                         <action type="Rewrite" url="keystone.js"/>
                    </rule>
               </rules>
          </rewrite>

          <security>
               <requestFiltering>
                    <hiddenSegments>
                         <remove segment="bin"/>
                    </hiddenSegments>
               </requestFiltering>
          </security>

          <httpErrors existingResponse="PassThrough" />

          <iisnode watchedFiles="web.config;*.js" debuggingEnabled="false" />
     </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Obviously, the error differs from yours. So, you may confirm whether your application runs fine locally before you deploy it to Azure. Also, note that `gzip` compression is enabled by default without any operation. You can check out [Azure Web App Not Using GZip Compression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34006236/azure-web-app-not-using-gzip-compression) and [gzip compression in Windows Azure Websites](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14722464/gzip-compression-in-windows-azure-websites) for details.

Comment: thanks for the effort. I think I have missconfigured something in my webapp. I have tried it again with a fresh one and it works now